# Different SQL server Versions on the same Windows

Tags: sql-server, windows-7

I need to have `SQL server 2005` and `SQL server 2014` on the same `Windows 7` machine.

My situation is as follows. I have 2 versions of the same program:

- The first version uses `SQL server 2005` databases with names `DB1` and `DB2`.
- The second version uses `SQL Server 2014` databases with the same names `DB1` and `DB2`.

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Did you try it? Did you have any issues?

Comment: They can be installed side-by-side; just ensure they have different instance names. Try the question on [dba](http://dba.stackexchange.com) exchange.

Comment: @VC1 If one version is installed , the other fail to install.

Comment: Any article when can i read how can i do it ?

Comment: @PeterSmith [Is cross-posting a question on multiple Stack Exchange sites permitted if the question is on-topic for each site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu). Accepted answer: NO.

Comment: @TT Thanks for that, I should have worded my comment differently.

Answer (score 2):

Although I have never tried the above combination I have installed mixed versions of SQL server on the same computer (with Windows 7). The method is:

- Always install the older version first
- When prompted give it an instance name
- Install the new version; don't choose the upgrade option
- Give it a different instance name

Remember that SQL server 2005 is now out of support so you will need to download the most recent service pack and install it manually.

You can read more about it [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143694.aspx).